# ERROR "Integer expression expected" ON BASH SCRIPT

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting

Script

```
#!/bin/bash
MEM=`ps -eo pid,ppid,cmd,%mem,%cpu --sort=-%mem | grep -i 4721 | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $4}'`
PID=4721
while true;
do
if [ $MEM -gt 94 ]; then
printf "mem has exceeded, kill it"
kill -9 $PID
echo "Killed the process"
        exit 0
    else
        echo "SIZE has not yet exceeding"
    fi

    sleep 10
done
```

OUTPUT

```
[root@ris-n-v10253 ~]# sh ash.sh
ash.sh: line 6: [: 1.3: integer expression expected
SIZE has not yet exceeding
```

Running `ps...`

```
ps -eo pid,ppid,cmd,%mem,%cpu --sort=-%mem | grep -i 4721 | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $4}'

1.3
```

Comment: Please reformat your question as a readable script.

Comment: You are not running bash, despite the shebang. Because you explicitly invoke the script with sh, it is run by sh and the shebang is just a comment. sh may be ksh or Bourne (original) shell on your system. ash is a genuine alternative shell and it is unwise to use ash.sh for your own script. Your posted error message also appears to be incomplete. And where does that 1.3 at the very end of your command (an the subject of the error message) come from?

Comment: The error is on line 6, and the only possible source is the value in MEM, which is `1.3`. Neither Bash not sh recognise non-integer values, which is why it says `integer expression expected`. You could have found this using `shellcheck.net`.

Answer (score 0):

Shell dislikes non-integer numbers (ksh excepted).

Easy solution is to have awk output the %age to the nearest integer. Replace all this:

```
grep -i 4721 | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $4}'
```

with this:

```
awk -v Pid="${PID}" '$1 == Pid { printf ("%d\n", int (0.5 + $4))' }
```

There are many other possible improvements:

Make the script executable, and run it as a command without specifying sh.

You initialise the PID variable, but you hard-code the same value in the previous command.

You sort the ps output, but then pick out a single line anyway.

If the cmd field from ps has any whitespace, the %mem field will not be in $4 any more. In fact, why output ppid, cmd, %cpu -- you don't use any of them?

You are rushing round a loop forever, every 10 seconds, to check the value of MEM. But you initialise it just once, before the loop, so it will never change again.

It might be helpful to do some more reporting:

Choose either printf or echo, for consistency.

Print which process (name and pid) is being killed, and by which script. Maybe even when it happened, and how long it had been running.

Helpful to report the actual %age found, not just that it didn't fail. This would help monitor the growth. In this case, it would also have shown you that it was flat-lining.